# can the TF_TRTwork with faster Rcnn inception v2 for object detection on nvidia geforce

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia, tensorrt

I am working on a object detection model to detect the car plates
i used faster rcnn inception v2 (COCO) to train and i got impressive result for accuracy, but the speed isn't that good i am trying to implement the system for real time human
so dose the tf_trt work with this model , and if dose can it work with Nvidia Geforce graphic card

please help me

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: TF-TRT applies optimizations wherever possible in the graph, falling back on the TF implementation where necessary. Faster R-CNN does indeed work in TF-TRT (I've been using it). About the GPU, it depends on the specific model you have

Comment: @GPhilo so there is no need for running the faster rcnn TF_TRT iam alreading using it on gpu but i want higher spped with the same accuracy

Comment: If using docker is an option, look into Nvidia's docker images for tensorflow with TensorRT, those come with some pretty good automatic graph optimizations that may give you some speedup. Don't expect a 10x speedup though